# How do I in Drupal 7 hook into the status message update area after saving a node and it says "updated node" to be a link to that node

Tags: nodes

In Drupal 7, after saving a node it redirects you back to the page of the node with the message status saying "blog 'title of blog' has been updated".

How do I turn that status message into the link of that node? I need to do this since I have rules setup where I have it redirect to another part of my site, and it just shows the status message of that node being updated. I just need that clickable. im assuming it would be a hook somewhere hook node save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) that responds to node updates. There you can add the link in [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7).

However you may get two status messages, a default status message and another the custom message you just created. For removing the default message you can use [Disable Messages](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Rules, you could add a reaction rule "*After saving content*" and use a "*Display message on site*" action to add your own message, e.g add a link using the node tokens available there. Configurable, and no code required.